# Reactjs onFocus/onBlur hide/show element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, show-hide

I have a two input field what I want is if I click the first one/ if I input the first one the 2nd field must be hidden. I have the codes here but I think I have some error in the syntax. sorry, i'm new in this language.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {data: ''}; 
}

onClick() {
    this.setState({ data : 'hidden'});
}

const elements = (
 <div>
     <label>Pick-up</label>
     <PlacesAutocomplete 
        inputProps={inputProps} 
        ref="pickupVehicle" 
        value={this.state.pickup} 
        onChange={this.handlepickupVehicle} 
        onClick={this.onClick} />
 </div>
 <div {this.state.data}>
     <label>Drop-off</label>   
     <PlacesAutocomplete 
        inputProps={inputProps2} 
        ref="dropoffVehicle" 
        value={this.state.destination} 
        onChange={this.handledropoffVehicle} />
 </div> );
```

and then if he has done inputting or the focus is out then the field show it again.

Comment: The code you posted is syntactically incorrect.  You have `jsx` statements within the body of what looks like a `React.Component`  class definition...

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot to add that the field is inside the function. my bad.

Comment: @Deee please add more code, can we see the `render` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest fix is:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {data: true}; 
}

onClick() {
  this.setState({ data : false} );
}

render() {
  const elements = (
    <div>
      <label>Pick-up</label>
      <PlacesAutocomplete 
        inputProps={inputProps} 
        ref="pickupVehicle" 
        value={this.state.pickup} 
        onChange={this.handlepickupVehicle} 
        onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} />
   </div>
   {this.state.data &&
     <div>
       <label>Drop-off</label>   
       <PlacesAutocomplete 
         inputProps={inputProps2} 
         ref="dropoffVehicle" 
         value={this.state.destination} 
         onChange={this.handledropoffVehicle} />
     </div> 
    }
  );

  return elements;
}
```

There's some points to be noticed:

- binding the onClick function (so that the "this" can be used): `this.onClick.bind(this)`
- use `{this.state.data && [JSX] }` for conditionally show/hide element block by its state

If you have further issues, please post here so we can get through together!

Answer (score 0):

You should have logic for [conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html) where on focus of input field one you set some flag to false, and on focus out you set the flag to true. Based on the flag you display second input like below:

```
render() {
    const showSecondInput = this.state.showSecondInput;
return (
    <input id="input1" type="text" onFocus={(e) => this.handleFocus(e)} onBlur={(e) => this.handleBlur(e)} .../>

    {showSecondInput &&
            <input id="input2" type="text" .../>
    }
)
};
```

Now the functions definitions should look like:

```
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showSecondInput : true
        };
    }

    function handleFocus(event){
        this.state ={
            showSecondInput : false
        };
    }

    function handleBlur(event){
        this.state ={
            showSecondInput : true
        };
    }
```

For your question, try below code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {data: true}; 
    this.onClick= this.onClick.bind(this);
}

onClick() {
    this.setState({ data : false} );
}

const elements = (
 <div>
 <label>Pick-up</label>
   <PlacesAutocomplete 
      inputProps={inputProps} 
      ref="pickupVehicle" 
      value={this.state.pickup} 
      onChange={this.handlepickupVehicle} 
      onClick={this.onClick} />
 </div>
{this.state.data && 
  <div>
   <label>Drop-off</label>   
      <PlacesAutocomplete 
         inputProps={inputProps2} 
         ref="dropoffVehicle" 
         value={this.state.destination} 
         onChange={this.handledropoffVehicle} />
</div> } );
```

Comment: thank you, sir, but still, it's not working as expected. :(

Comment: This may be because while passing event handlers for onClick, onFocus etc. you need to bind with this. like: this.handlepickupVehicle= this.handlepickupVehicle.bind(this) in constructor.

Comment: Thanks, Manu :) I really appreciated your effort but it didn't work. :(

Comment: no worries, then your problem may be something else. Debug your code properly.