# Render a component within a component from onClick event in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Here is a short demo of what I am trying to accomplish](https://i.gyazo.com/75e1ca6c811b61d71d65482f4bca4d92.mp4).

When "Tickers" is active in the menu, it should bring up the `Tabs` component. When other menu items are active, the `Tabs` component should not be rendered. I have a Content, `SideMenu`, and `Tabs` component. It seems to me that the best way to accomplish this would be to pass states around between components. So the button in the `SideMenu` component will trigger the Content component to `render` the `Tabs` component. How do I go about doing this?

**Content.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Grid, Image, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import '../index.css';

import Tabs from './content/Tabs';
import SideMenu from './content/SideMenu';

class Content extends React.Component{

  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  render(){

    return(
      <div>
        <Grid relaxed columns='equal' padded>
          <Grid.Column width={2} >
            <SideMenu />
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width = {1}>
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={10}>
            <Tabs />
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Content
```

**SideMenu.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react'


export default class SideMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = { activeItem: 'Tickers' };
  }


  handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })

  render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state

    return (
      <Menu pointing secondary vertical>
        <Menu.Item name='Tickers' active={activeItem === 'Tickers'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
        <Menu.Item name='All Time Highs' active={activeItem === 'All Time Highs'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
        <Menu.Item name='Article Sentiment' active={activeItem === 'Article Sentiment'} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />
      </Menu>
    )
  }
}
```

**Tabs.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Tab } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const panes = [
  { menuItem: 'Tab 1', render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}>Tab 1 Content</Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 2', render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}>Tab 2 Content</Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 3', render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}>Tab 3 Content</Tab.Pane> },
]

const Tabs = () => (
  <Tab menu={{ secondary: true }} panes={panes} />
)

export default Tabs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have solution for that, you can move the `activeItem` and `handleItemClick` to `Content.js` and then passing to side menu component, so we can make conditional rendering in `Content.js`

`Content.Js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { Grid, Image, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'

import Tabs from './content/Tabs';
import SideMenu from './content/SideMenu';

class Content extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = { activeItem: 'Tickers' }; //move state from SideMenu.js
  }
  handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name }) //move function onClick from SideMenu.js
  render(){
    const { activeItem } = this.state //call the state
    return(
      <div>
        <Grid relaxed columns='equal' padded>
          <Grid.Column width={2} >
            <SideMenu handleItemClick={this.handleItemClick} activeItem={activeItem} /> {/* passing the handleItemClick and activeItem */}
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width = {1}>
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={10}>
            { this.state.activeItem === 'Tickers' && //this is for conditional render Tabs.js
              <Tabs />
            }
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and then in your `SideMenu.js` access the data from `Content.js` using `this.props`

`SideMenu.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react'


export default class SideMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props); //move state to Content.js
  }
  // move function to Content.js
  render() {
    //move state to Content.js
    return (
      <Menu pointing secondary vertical>
        {/* access activeItem and handleItemClick using this.props */}
        <Menu.Item name='Tickers' active={this.props.activeItem === 'Tickers'} onClick={this.props.handleItemClick} />
        <Menu.Item name='All Time Highs' active={this.props.activeItem === 'All Time Highs'} onClick={this.props.handleItemClick} />
        <Menu.Item name='Article Sentiment' active={this.props.activeItem === 'Article Sentiment'} onClick={this.props.handleItemClick} />
      </Menu>
    )
  }
}
```

I hope that can help you, please notice me if you have an error, thanks  :)

Answer (score 1):

You should have logic for conditional rendering where on click you set some flag. Based on the flag you can display nested component like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45726355/5346095).